# How to suspend only under certain conditions?

Tags: 16.04, suspend

**The story:** my laptop has an integrated intel videocard and an nvidia graphical coprocessor. I use nvidia proprietary driver which allows to switch between the two (via nvidia-prime), so I can use the integrated video when working and switch to nvidia for games. The problem is I can only suspend when using intel video; if nvidia is in use then the laptop fails to wake from suspend. 
While I figure out the solution to the main bug (failure to wake from suspend) I want to ban suspend if nvidia is in use.

**The goal:** whenever a suspend signal arrives -- from explicitly pressing the "suspend" button, closing the lid, or after the predefined time of inactivity, -- I want to perform a check of which videocard is in use. If it's nvidia I want the system to ignore the suspend signal. How do I implement this conditional suspend?
You can assume in your answer that I have a bash script which returns "INTEL" if intel is in use and "NVIDIA" if nvidia is in use.

(If someone tells me how to check which videocard is in use and/or the solution to the suspend bug that'd also be appreciated but would not be a valid answer to the main question.)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 x64 MATE and Linux Mint 18 x64 Cinnamon. My hardware is Intel i7-6500U with Intel HD Graphics 520, and Nvidia GTX 960M.